# webview flutter : scroll to element?

Tags: flutter, webview

I have a webview with https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter package.

I would like to scroll to an anchor inside the webview from outside the webview by calling javascript scrollTo, but it doesnt work. Any ideas plesae? Here is a full example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class WebviewTest extends StatefulWidget {
  WebviewTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WebviewTest> createState() => _WebviewTestState();
}

final htmlKey = GlobalKey();

class _WebviewTestState extends State<WebviewTest> {
  late WebViewController _webViewController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        //elevation: 0.0,
        label: const Text("Check"),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
        onPressed: () {
          scrollToCurrent();
        },
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 400,
          child: WebView(
            onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
              _webViewController = controller;
            },
            initialUrl: Uri.dataFromString(
                    '<!DOCTYPE html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></head><body>' +
                        testHTML +
                        "</body></html>",
                    mimeType: 'text/html')
                .toString(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void scrollToCurrent() {
    _webViewController.loadUrl(
        "javascript:document.getElementById(\"TESTING\").scrollIntoView()");
  }
}

const testHTML =
    '<div id="lipsum"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer sit amet lobortis lectus, vitae cursus sapien. Quisque posuere placerat vulputate. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur imperdiet velit in elit efficitur, ac tempus eros egestas. Aliquam eget interdum velit, eu viverra enim. Fusce sem dolor, rutrum tempus tristique ut, aliquam semper eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce dictum, nisi at porttitor placerat, ex risus dignissim augue, vitae aliquet nisl ex in dolor. Fusce faucibus orci eu dui porta pellentesque. Quisque ornare ligula in dolor ullamcorper, a luctus ipsum maximus. Maecenas est sem, hendrerit vitae erat sed, facilisis ornare tellus. Cras tortor mi, feugiat pretium pulvinar sit amet, aliquam sed enim. Vivamus finibus mauris et erat sollicitudin, vitae condimentum nisl feugiat. Quisque luctus ligula id ipsum ultrices dignissim. Integer mattis scelerisque felis. Morbi dictum massa at nunc tristique mattis.</p><p>Maecenas ac ultricies felis, id dignissim nibh. Etiam in neque mauris. Fusce ullamcorper, nulla in elementum bibendum, nisi dolor imperdiet magna, vel pulvinar tellus quam vel tellus. Nulla malesuada diam eros, eget pulvinar nisl laoreet a. In commodo quam mauris, nec congue metus tincidunt a. Vestibulum vitae fermentum justo, laoreet dictum arcu. Suspendisse quis enim nisi.</p><p>Etiam dictum finibus leo id ultrices. Nunc ornare risus rutrum leo iaculis, eu hendrerit eros molestie. Phasellus massa risus, interdum ut felis ut, tristique feugiat sem. Vivamus quis faucibus tortor, in tempor odio. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In eu turpis in leo bibendum ornare. Pellentesque ut eros sit amet libero porttitor finibus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Ut ac iaculis leo. Nam ut dui id nulla porta convallis.</p><p>Maecenas fermentum ipsum elit, porta ornare sem aliquet eget. Proin id commodo odio, et ultricies libero. Maecenas eget sodales nibh. Fusce interdum velit luctus scelerisque mattis. Nunc ut vulputate dolor. Sed lacus lorem, aliquet maximus commodo quis, posuere sit amet ligula. Cras volutpat, orci id commodo efficitur, felis erat gravida lorem, vitae consequat felis justo sed felis.</p><p>Duis vitae accumsan nisi. Donec placerat, libero vitae accumsan auctor, est velit luctus magna, porttitor placerat tortor ex ac purus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse ac nunc venenatis nulla feugiat egestas. Cras a neque sed augue malesuada posuere. Etiam ultricies orci a neque efficitur blandit. Nunc ac auctor leo. Nunc lacinia sem in justo egestas sollicitudin. Ut ac mi maximus, sollicitudin lorem ut, dictum augue. Proin vestibulum nisl eu ullamcorper accumsan. Praesent ornare dui eu justo consectetur, vel sollicitudin est interdum. Donec sodales, tortor nec porttitor porta, dui turpis sodales libero, in pharetra lectus quam sed velit. Cras pharetra id turpis ac fringilla. Nunc lacus felis, tempor eu urna ac, tincidunt rutrum nunc.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer sit amet lobortis lectus, vitae cursus sapien. Quisque posuere placerat vulputate. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur imperdiet velit in elit efficitur, ac tempus eros egestas. Aliquam eget interdum velit, eu viverra enim. Fusce sem dolor, rutrum tempus tristique ut, aliquam semper eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce dictum, nisi at porttitor placerat, ex risus dignissim augue, vitae aliquet nisl ex in dolor. Fusce faucibus orci eu dui porta pellentesque. Quisque ornare ligula in dolor ullamcorper, a luctus ipsum maximus. Maecenas est sem, hendrerit vitae erat sed, facilisis ornare tellus. Cras tortor mi, feugiat pretium pulvinar sit amet, aliquam sed enim. Vivamus finibus mauris et erat sollicitudin, vitae condimentum nisl feugiat. Quisque luctus ligula id ipsum ultrices dignissim. Integer mattis scelerisque felis. Morbi dictum massa at nunc tristique mattis.</p><p>Maecenas ac ultricies felis, id dignissim nibh. Etiam in neque mauris. Fusce ullamcorper, nulla in elementum bibendum, nisi dolor imperdiet magna, vel pulvinar tellus quam vel tellus. Nulla malesuada diam eros, eget pulvinar nisl laoreet a. In commodo quam mauris, nec congue metus tincidunt a. Vestibulum vitae fermentum justo, laoreet dictum arcu. Suspendisse quis enim nisi.</p><p>Etiam dictum finibus leo id ultrices. Nunc ornare risus rutrum leo iaculis, eu hendrerit eros molestie. Phasellus massa risus, interdum ut felis ut, tristique feugiat sem. Vivamus quis faucibus tortor, in tempor odio. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In eu turpis in leo bibendum ornare. Pellentesque ut eros sit amet libero porttitor finibus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Ut ac iaculis leo. Nam ut dui id nulla porta convallis.</p><p>Maecenas fermentum ipsum elit, porta ornare sem aliquet eget. Proin id commodo odio, et ultricies libero. Maecenas eget sodales nibh. Fusce interdum velit luctus scelerisque mattis. Nunc ut vulputate dolor. Sed lacus lorem, aliquet maximus commodo quis, posuere sit amet ligula. Cras volutpat, orci id commodo efficitur, felis erat gravida lorem, vitae consequat felis justo sed felis.</p><p>Duis vitae accumsan nisi. Donec placerat, libero vitae accumsan auctor, est velit luctus magna, porttitor placerat tortor ex ac purus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse ac nunc venenatis nulla feugiat egestas. Cras a neque sed augue malesuada posuere. Etiam ultricies orci a neque efficitur blandit. Nunc ac auctor leo. Nunc lacinia sem in justo egestas sollicitudin. Ut ac mi maximus, sollicitudin lorem ut, <a id="TESTING" href="">dictum augue</a>. Proin vestibulum nisl eu ullamcorper accumsan. Praesent ornare dui eu justo consectetur, vel sollicitudin est interdum. Donec sodales, tortor nec porttitor porta, dui turpis sodales libero, in pharetra lectus quam sed velit. Cras pharetra id turpis ac fringilla. Nunc lacus felis, tempor eu urna ac, tincidunt rutrum nunc.</p></div>';
```